# How to split string in TSV file

Tags: text-processing, text-editor, text, cut-command, tr

I have TSV file like this:

```
abc_1
def_2
ghi_3
jkl_4
mno_5
```

I want to split that in to the:

```
abc 
def 
ghi 
jkl
mno
```

and

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How I can get that?

Comment: Welcome! When you say split them, you mean ouput each result in a different file?

Comment: Yes, I mean as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

Split by character position:

To obtain the first output (here, the output is redirected to a file called *first_output*) use:

```
cut -c1-3 your_input_file >first_output
```

To obtain the second output use:

```
cut -c5- your_input_file >second_output
```

Here, the option `-c` means "select only the characters specified." The list following the option `-c` specifies the character positions or ranges (where `1` is the first character in the line).

### Method 2

Split according to delimiter:

```
cut -f1 -d_ your_input_file >first_output
cut -f2 -d_ your_input_file >second_output
```

Here, the option `-d` indicates the delimiting character (`_` in our case) and the option `-f` indicates field position to select.

Comment: It works well, thank you so much

Comment: These are only some of the methods you can use. However, you mentioned about TSV. Where are the tabs in your input file?

Comment: Actually my TSV file only have 1 column with billions rows. Ah,  it means my data is a list not a TSV file. Am I right?

Comment: If all the lines in the file are like this (`xxx_x`), then OK.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '{ print $1 > "file_1"; print $2 > "file_2" }' source_file
```

Comment: It works well, thank you for your help